# How do you open the font picker for a UITextField in Xcode4?

Tags: xcode4, uitextfield

In Xcode 3 you used to simply use Cmd T.

However, in Xcode 4 this now opens a new tab.

What's the shortcut (or menu command) to open the font picker for a UITextField in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut to open a font picker is: control + command + shift + T